# Map not showing while following tutorial for QGIS

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPE2M.png)I downloaded and installed QGIS 3.4 and tried to load an example shapefile layer as described in [this tutorial](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/introduction/preparation.html#basic-fa-prepare-a-map) using the provided shapefiles.

But the images are not showing up. I tried to uninstall/reinstall but it didn't help. What am I doing wrong?
Here is what I'm getting.
[[image: here is what I'm getting.]]
Here is the attribute table
[image]

Comment: It couldn't be that you're following a tutorial written for 2.18 in version 3.4.. could you please explain how you modified the instructions for your installed version please. Do the provided shapefiles have *all their bits*? i.e. not just .shp but .dbf, .shx etc.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it’s now linked to the correct tutorial, but that doesn’t solve the problem

Comment: The Shapefiles do come with.dbf and .shx files, but the tutorial doesn’t say I need to do anything with those. Should I?

Comment: Never mind! I did another uninstall/reinstall and now it works